# Do I require NESTED promises for this task?

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to run `hideSaveCancel() and loadPage()` after an array of forms has been iterated, during which, each form will be the subject of an async call to insert/update in the database, initiated by the line `postObject.preparePost(formData)`

```
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form.dirty')).forEach(
            f => {
                postObject = new Object();
                formData = buildFormDataObject(f);
                eval(`postObject = ${f.dataset['jsobj']}`);
                postObject.preparePost(formData);
            }
        )
    }).then(() => {
        hideSaveCancel();
        loadPage(postSavePage, postSaveArgs);
    });
```

I don't understand whether I require multiple promises (one for the array and another for the async calls) or one for the whole process, and ...

I need to understand how to send the "completion" message, so that the hideSaveCancel and loadPage are called after all the form updates have completed.

Comment: WTH is that `eval` call supposed to achieve? Don't do that.

Comment: So you're saying `postObject.preparePost(…)` is an asynchronous call returning a promise, and everything else is synchronous?

Comment: What is `preparePost`? Can you add the definition of that method?

Comment: @Bergi  I want to instantiate an object in the code which I can identify by the value in the dataset property.  I did read about 'eval' before hand, and saw the warnings, but a. I didn't twig how that eval could be dangerous - perhaps you might kindly enlighten me;  b. I was trying to avoid a length switch statement.  In retrospect, perhaps I should return to the ```switch``` statement.  I appreciate you asking.

Comment: Since we cannot see what code `f.dataset['jsobj']` contains, I cannot tell what it's doing and how you'd do it the best way. (If I had to guess, it seems that `jsobj` contains a JSON string, so you should use `var postObject = JSON.parse(f.dataset.jsobj);` instead of calling `eval`).

Comment: Apologies @Bergi, for clarification, all it contains is two or three letters, e.g. "HL", which would match an object previously defined as HL.  I should probably drop this approach and implement a ```switch``` statement - I guess that I was trying to be unnecessarily terse.

Comment: Or better, a lookup `Map` like `const objects = new Map([["HL", HL], …])` where you'd just use `objects.get(f.dataset.jsobj)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Promise.all(
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form.dirty')).map(
    f => {
      postObject = new Object();
      formData = buildFormDataObject(f);
      eval(`postObject = ${f.dataset['jsobj']}`);
      // return the promise
      return postObject.preparePost(formData);
    }
  )
)
.then(() => {
  hideSaveCancel();
  // you can chain it even further if you return the promise
  return loadPage(postSavePage, postSaveArgs);
})
```

EDIT: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjgVwKYCcCeBlJAbJwogoQBKSUCKYAlmAOYBihAthDALwwDaAsAFAwwAJiGAImSMFAB0wFEgCGUJAFFc4yQAoA5ADNmWgJQAaPgOGj102QqWqkl7XpRNDJ-kJFiJVuYpVrvR31jPgBdAG4%20KN5QSFgAIwQqbEFGZwARRXl2GA0dAC4YAAkAFQBZABk0pjtLA0LSUBRBAB5oFBpaIxh5MDQAPnZBgG9TGFjoGCcmHLAkAHcYasyoeTyDSPcJ2EEshrxCVvbO7t6BnOGAX02BJ1ztrgBrJDRugDd5bGRQmBAdKeYBhgo3cZiynGeaB%20HA%20XyQNxglzGcnIlCEWU2SN4fAeEBA4gq4FoAAUUCIkBAICUABaKLBgQQkJCICmwDgaXarfZNI5QDp0U59fr1GCk-FUCBIFpgMTxVCDNgjMYPXBQCAYXBIAAOaQw%20KQZVYHDKimpUh02BAhA0AFYAAx2mAAahgJqgZpQvWETA0QIAVDAAIwOu0bZFkChgGBzRZipgSpAaDngJDdHTyZJAxXAsYCSVQEpUcQgBBQJNZwbCOYaVXqzU6wh68SG4wwWsapDa3X6lsIy5h3hYvhxhNST7YDRjACCKE9aHNZJ9LPQWFw%20EITNR1Do1QgBikTHkWsnoKmQ2BAkvMFzl4enOyHESyVSzBWax0A6vAgA9N%20YCjIxgd0kBgLVFwTG8BAAtE8QJIkxWACkqVpKB6UZUgWWgDksgMG8sQEXDeEIqRgLAJMIHrNAKxzLZwDxXApEtWgNAozstSozENiAA)

```
const querySelectorsReturningForms = [
  document.createElement('form'),
  document.createElement('form'),
  document.createElement('form'),
];


const buildFormData = (f: HTMLFormElement): Record<string, any> => {
  const form = new FormData(f);
  const data: Record<string, any> = {};
  for (const [key, value] of form) {
    data[key] = value;
  }
  return data;
}

const someLongProcessThatSendsRequest = (data: Record<string, any>): Promise<number> => {
  const letsSleepForSomeMs = Math.floor(500 + Math.random() * 1000);
  return new Promise((done, fail) => {
    setTimeout(() => done(letsSleepForSomeMs), letsSleepForSomeMs);
  });
}

Promise.all(
  Array.from(querySelectorsReturningForms).map(
    f => {      
      const data = buildFormData(f);
      // return the promise
      return someLongProcessThatSendsRequest(data)
    }
  )
)
.then((sleepy) => {
  console.log(sleepy);
});
```

Comment: Cheers, I will check this approach too.  :)

Comment: Hi.  By using ```return postObject....``` would you expect that process to have to complete before the response is received?  My present problem is that the ```Promise.all``` is not waiting for the async calls to complete before it moves on to ```then```   :)

Comment: It works on my end, I also posted a playground link. The issue is in your returned function imho. Cant help without more information

Comment: The returned function is an ajax API call to update a db - I'm using jQuery to make that API call, as follows:

function postForm(dbAction, dataValues, clazz) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'a url',
        data: { ... },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: (response) => {
             if (undefined === postSaveArgs) {
                postSaveArgs = { id: response['lastInsertID'] };
            }
        },
        error: (e) => errorHandler(e),
    }).done(
        (response) => { }
    )
}

Comment: It seems you are not returning a promise from postForm. Look it up how to promisify your ajax request with jQuery and return it from postForm. Also, add it to your original question, because that is the buggy part.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it like so...

```js
let requests = [];

[...document.querySelectorAll('form.dirty')].forEach(form => {
    const formData = buildFormDataObject(form);
    const postObject = form.dataset['jsobj'];
    requests.push(postObject.preparePost(formData));
});

Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
    hideSaveCancel();
    loadPage(postSavePage, postSaveArgs);
});
```

Basically building an array of all your requests and using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve once all have completed. This approach allows you to implement better error handling for each response (if you wanted).

Note: I removed your `eval` statement for the sake of this answer because it's an enormous security risk.

Comment: What is the array spread good for?

Comment: @Bergi in this case it’s just preference.

Comment: But… why? You don't write `Promise.all([...requests])` either

Comment: @Bergi it’s essentially the same thing as you’re doing with `Array.from()`, converting a NodeList to an array. However, it looks like most browsers now support `.forEach()` on node lists (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) so you could remove the array spread altogether.

Comment: Yes, all browsers that do support `[Symbol.iterator]` on node lists also do support `forEach` on node lists, that what I was getting at. (Notice that in older browsers that had non-iterable nodelists, `Array.from` still works because it can convert array-like objects; array spread syntax does not work there)

Comment: @LeviCole  Thank you, I like the look of that approach;  I had actually wondered whether there might be an approach using an array to muster all of the calls together - I have done something similar with a situation in some Angular/RXJS.

Will give it a go. :)

Comment: @LeviCole  This has been helpful to me, but it's not a complete solution to the question.  I need the callbacks to fire after the ASYNC call within each ```postObject.preparePost(formData) ``` has completed.  The current solution appears to be getting to ```then``` once all of the async calls have been triggered.  This is why I suspect that I need an inner promise, and perhaps I will need to count them so that the completion is sent after the last one has had a response from the api.